# How to write names of different things specified by their kinds?

Tags: names

I'm interested in the particular case of writing the name of thing connected with the kind of thing. For example, I would write *the "Enter" button*, *the "Hello World" script*, etc.

Is this correct? Could it be written in another way?

Because also we have *The River Thames* and *River Thames*, but *the Mississippi River*...

Answer (score 1):

Geographic proper nouns are a special case, particularly given to variable word order. "Crater Lake," "Lake Tahoe." "Mount Rainier," "Grandfather Mountain" (this one, at least, consistently matches "mount" or "mountain" to the two orders).

In most everyday contexts, the category follows the instance. "The front door," "the Disney channel." There are a few other very unusual edge cases ("The Brothers Karamazov"), but for the most part it's "the 'Enter' button."

Comment: (Self-question: Then what about "her novel *The Hours*"? "His album *Live at the Acropolis*"? Is... is this because... I'm going to say this usage is different than "the 'Hello World' script" because... because these proper nouns can be recognized on their own and don't need "novel" or "album"? Oh dear, I'm confused.)

Comment: It's like _Præsident Linkoln_!

Comment: @nemo Well, that's a _title_, and that's a whole nuther matter, Captain Nemo.